# Manipulating HTML Data with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have some HTML that I'm trying to insert into a DB but it's proven harder than I thought.

The HTML looks like that (the id value is static, every question has id78questionRegion as an id):

```
<div class="fullquestion">
<div class='question'>House Frey are Bannermen sworn to which House?</div><div style=" visibility:visible; " id="id78questionRegion">


<a href="javascript:___gid_10(0)"><span>House Baratheon</span></a>

<a href="javascript:___gid_10(1)"><span>House Tyrell</span></a>

<a href="javascript:___gid_10(2)"><span>House Arryn</span></a>

<a href="javascript:___gid_10(3)"><span>House Stark</span></a>

<a href="javascript:___gid_10(4)"><span>House Tully</span></a>

</div><div class='answer'>House Tully</div>
</div>
```

And the PHP

```
 <?php

 $type = '';
 require ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/inc/db.php');
 require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/admin/simple_html_dom.php');

 $file = 'qa.html';
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file($file);
 $qcount = 100;
 for ($i = 0; $i <= $qcount; $i++) {
  echo 'Question is:<br>';
  echo $html->find('.question', $i);
  echo 'Possible Answers are:<br>';
  foreach ($html->find('#id78questionRegion a span', $i) as $question) {
   echo $html->find('#id78questionRegion a span');
  }

  echo 'Answer is:<br>';
  echo $html->find('.answer', $i);
 }
 ?>
```

I would like to have to have the question, each possible answer in a var as well as the correct answer but I can't figure out how to get the answers properly. Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are there 100 questions on this page? Is that why you have the counter? Is each question a multiple choice of 5 answers?

Comment: Yes. And no possible answers between 2 and 5. I'll look into your answer in a half hour. Thank you!

Comment: the id value is static, every question has id78questionRegion as an id

Comment: your code outputs every possible answers for every question

Comment: It is an invalid DOM if all the questions have the same ID but I'm working on a solution for you, anyway. Hang Tight.

Comment: It is, but it's not my code... I don't mind using some other tools to do this, the result is the only thing that matters here. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I've made some edits. Give that a try. I'm new to the `simple_html_dom` plugin so be patient. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach ($html->find('.fullquestion') as $fq) {
  echo 'Question is: <br />';
  $question = $fq->find('.question');
  echo $question->innertext . '<br />\n';
  echo 'Possible answers are: <br \>';
  foreach ($fq->find('span') as $a) {
    echo $a->innertext . '<br />\n';
  }
  echo 'Correct answer is: <br \>';
  $answer = $fq->find('.answer');
  echo $answer->innertext . "<br /><br />\n";
}
```

Comment: That was basically my code, I don't get it... The possible answers are good. Question and Answer are returnning an Array but I should be able to figure this on my own. Thanks

Comment: $answer = $fq->find('.answer' ,0); did it. Thanks again